# Match function in Microsoft 365 Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I get a compile error when trying to use Match function saying

> sub or function not defined

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim A, B, Addrs As String
    B = Cells(1, 2)
    A = Match(B, ActiveSheet.Columns(1), 0)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Match` or `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use worksheet functions directly to `VBA`. Use the `WorksheetFunction` property of the Application object to return the `WorksheetFunction` object. Read this article from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) to explore more...

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim A, B, Addrs As String
    B = Cells(1, 2)
    A = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(B, ActiveSheet.Columns(1), 0)
    MsgBox A
End Sub
```